# Is it legal to listen to aviation frequencies in the UK?

Tags: radio-communications

Am i allowed to purchase an ATC scanner and listen tho what is being said in the control tower? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can purchase a scanner - these are freely available in the UK.

No, legally, you can't listen to air traffic control. However, in real life, this is generally not enforced. Go to any airshow or airport observation area and you'll find people using scanners openly.

Comment: Why is it illegal to listen to ATC in the U.K.?

Comment: @CarloFelicione It's part of a broad brush of regulations covering snail mail, electronic comms and radio (amongst other types) which make it illegal to receive communications not intended for you.